# Prevent my Windows App to cause Windows Runtime Broker to run out of Memory

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, uwp

When my Windows 10 app runs, it causes a process called `Runtime Broker` to execute, which takes up a lot of Memory space.

[image: Runtime Broker]

I know my app isn't "Memory-hungry" and it hardly takes 80 MB of RAM to execute. But from the time it starts, the Memory used by `Runtime Broker` keeps in increasing until the PC gets stuck.

Upon killing that process, the app is force closed by Windows.

I would have posted my source code here, if only I knew which part of the code is causing this to happen.

What are the possible **technical reasons** for this problem to happen, and **what are the possible fixes in my code to prevent this?**

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it some API that I am calling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the RuntimeBroker.exe process in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/q/500089/52365)

Comment: I realized this question have been asked before. I edited my question to focus more on **How to prevent this issue to happen because of my app**

Comment: You probably have a memory leak. Hard to tell without seeing the code. This probably isn't something that Stack Overflow can debug for you.

Comment: @CodyGray Apparently ["there have been users who've experienced memory related issues with this particular .exe"](http://superuser.com/a/707745/52365)

Comment: @VijayChavda This is killing me since last 2 days! I haven't found an answer to this online, the only difference now is that it is running under the process of my UWP application (I can see the application process along with RunTimeBroker process). How did you manage to fix this one?

Comment: @Anss I didn't. I had to discontinue whatever I was doing. It's still an open question.. Check out comments above to know more about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete RuntimeBroker.exe and any other file. I deleted RuntimeBroker.exe and Livecomm.exe by booting a live Linux Dvd and after loading go and mount the c: drive then simply navigate to the file and delete it. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Runtimebroker seems to hold about 60k per file held via StorageFile objects. It's still a bad problem and the only solution is to not hold on to very many of these.

Microsoft just never does anything about this.

Update: Microsoft seems to have quietly ditched UWP. The replacement has "WinUI" and is probably called the Windows App SDK at the moment. No more runtimebroker.exe.